# Сделать редирект с ряда страниц на главную сайта

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Есть страницы

```
mysite.net/coupon-tags/bags
mysite.net/coupon-tags/watches
```

и таких десятки.

Нужно выставить редиректы со всех страниц, которые начинаются на
`mysite.net/coupon-tags` на главную страницу сайта, т.е на `mysite.net`

Подскажите пожалуйста, что надо для этого прописать в htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле **.htaccess**, который лежит в корне сайта, сразу после строки

```
RewriteEngine On
```

добавляете строку

```
RewriteRule ^coupon\-tags\/ http://mysite.net/? [L,R=301]
```

где `http://mysite.net` - ваш сайт (может и `https://mysite.net`).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Сработало!